# How significant is the "amount of queries used" to site performance/speed?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I've been wondering how significant is the amount of queries used to site performance/speed.

I have two websites, running with different engines (one with IPB and another with MyBB). The IPB one has less queries used (only 14 on average), but it runs slower than MyBB with more queries used (average on 20).

I thought this is because the IPB is heavily-modded, so I run a fresh-install on my localhost.

But it still results the same. The IPB (which has less queries) runs slower than MyBB (with more queries).

This makes me wonder, so how is queries used affecting the site performance? Is it significant?

Comment: This is probably better off on programmers.stackexchange.com. You aren't really comparing anything here. One system could have 20 very small queries while the other could have 10 small queries and 4 big ones or whatever combination thereof.

Comment: Actually I'm not trying to compare IPB with MyBB. Those are only example. Since I'm not really a programmer; I was just confused why the queries doesn't seem to really affect front-end performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well quantity of queries is one factor. But you also have to consider each individual query, does it do joins? Lots of Math? Queries within queries? Do the tables have indexes etc.

Take a look at these links on optimisation, knowing how to optimise something can tell you what can cause it to slow down.

http://www.fiftyfoureleven.com/weblog/web-development/programming-and-scripts/mysql-optimization-tip

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650689.aspx

http://hungred.com/useful-information/ways-optimize-sql-queries/

Comment: Thanks! It's difficult to choose which answer is the most informative but I think the links you give out quite helps me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question has many answers. There are many things to consider. For example, querying a db which will return A LOT of lines will take more time than a DB which has ust a few records. Another thing to consider is the number of queries, just as you are doing within your post. Another case i can think of is how you do the queries. If you are using jquery or javascript ajax calls to make the queries they will take a lot more time.

Answer (score 1):

Sheer number of queries per page does not correlate with site responsiveness and speed.

What does matter is:

- What those queries actually are?
- How well DB server can cope with the load that they generate?
- Are they executed serially or in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what You consider 'significant'.
Let's consider two scenarios:

**We have 'lots' of queries that take quite some time to execute**

It's bad... Just because it takes much time to process them all

**We have 'lots' of queries that take very little time to execute**

If Your database server is on different machine as web server it might be a problem due to communication overhead. Web server and database server will most probably spend more time on communication then on processing each query (think of network latency).

If Your database server is on the same machine as web server it might not affect site performance much as communication between web server and database server will be very quick. BUT there are other things to consider. For example You might be locking some tables for update/select queries A LOT and it will decrease site performance considerably.

It's always better to execute less queries.

Answer (score 1):

You should remember that on an average website ~80% is about frontend performance and only 20% about backend performance.

So for website performance it is in most cases more relevant to optimize frontend performance. Here you can make the big points quickly.

Well, of course there are scenarios with sites heavily displaying LOTS of data coming from a DB. Here it is worth to think about optimizing backend performance. And optimizing backend performance means optimizing database stuff in most cases.

A good book about this is "High Performance Web Sites" from Steve Souders.

Comment: Thanks. I'd make sure to go check the book. Is it easy to read for non-programmers?

Comment: This book is about Frontend-Performance. I'd say it is not "hardcore technical" and may be easy to read for non-programmers. Nevertheless you need some knowledge about website programming and HTTP communication between server and client to really understand each and every of the 14 rules in this book. But even without this it can make sense reading and following these rules - they are concrete advices to follow. And it is good to follow them even when you do not really understand the reasons. Many of them are easy to follow and may be a bit harder to understand why for non-programmers.

Comment: Before buying you may want to check this: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html Steve Souders was former Performance Chief at Yahoo! and most of the rules from his book you can also find on this webpage. It also may give you an idea if the book is worth reading for you.